# Editable Grid Stopped Working for MS Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: grid, dynamics-crm-2011, customization, entities

Im and intern customizing Dynamics CRM 2011.  Downloaded Sonoma Partners Editable Grid.  Tested it last week for "managed" entities and was working fine.  Came in today and is not working.  Any thoughts?

Comment: please share more details (involved entities, what is exactly not working, is visible/not visible, did you try to reinstall it, ...)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a 3rd party (Managed solution) I suggest that you contact the developers for that solution. Otherwise more detail is needed...

What is the fault/error?